# How do I suppress the language field only for references which are in the English language in Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, zotero

I'm aware you can use `AtEveryBibItem` like so:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \clearlist{language}
}
```

But this removes the language field from every reference; can you suppress it for English only (or any other specific language) and not in other languages?

Edit: Should have made clear that I'm using the `beamer` package - so perhaps this has affected something?

Also:

---

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english, aspectratio = 169, notes]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, doi=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}
%\AtEveryBibitem{
%  \clearlist{language}
%}

\usepackage{nameref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\currentname}{\@currentlabelname}
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\section{Blah blah blah}
\begin{frame}{Blah 1}

blah blah blah \cite{cited_reference}

\end{frame}


\section{References and further reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References and further reading}
    \setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot showing example reference with language code.]

---

Edit 2:

@moewe This is the source of `cited_reference`:

```
@article{cited_reference,
    title = {The frame/content theory of evolution of speech production},
    volume = {21},
    issn = {0140-525X, 1469-1825},
    url = {https://www.cambridge.org/core/product/identifier/S0140525X98001265/type/journal_article},
    doi = {10.1017/S0140525X98001265},
    abstract = {ABSTRACT REMOVED AS IS TOO LONG},
    language = {en},
    number = {4},
    urldate = {2021-11-17},
    journal = {Behavioral and Brain Sciences},
    author = {MacNeilage, Peter F.},
    month = aug,
    year = {1998},
    pages = {499--511},
}
```

It seems like changing `en` to `english` in the language field removes the language field. However I have quite a few entries which **are** `en` and as they come through automatically from Zotero it would be a pain to change manually.

**Is there any way then to exclude these `en` fields without affecting others?**

Comment: you didn't provide an example so I couldn't test it, but imho biblatex will not show it for the main language of your document, so simply set \usepackage[english]{babel}.

Comment: Hm, yep I have set that, will put up a minimal example!

Comment: Can you show us the source of the relevant entry `cited_reference`, please?

Comment: @moewe just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` has a feature to suppress the output of the `language` field if the field value coincides with the current document language. This feature (`clearlang`) is enabled by default.

In order for this feature to work correctly, the `language` field must be filled with values that `biblatex` understands. The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) says

> The language(s) of the work. Languages may be specified literally or as localisation keys. If localisation keys are used, the prefix `lang` is omissible.

The `clearlang` feature essentially only works if the language of the work is given via a localisation key (possibly without the `lang` prefix). All known localisation keys are listed in §4.9.2.18 *Language Names* of the `biblatex` documentation.

So for an English work, you need `language = {english},` or `language = {langenglish},` instead of `language = {en},` for this to work.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{cited_reference,
  title    = {The frame/content theory of evolution of speech production},
  volume   = {21},
  doi      = {10.1017/S0140525X98001265},
  language = {english},
  number   = {4},
  journal  = {Behavioral and Brain Sciences},
  author   = {MacNeilage, Peter F.},
  month    = aug,
  year     = {1998},
  pages    = {499--511},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,cited_reference}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MacNeilage, Peter F. (Aug. 1998). “The frame/content theory of evolution of speech production”. In: Behavioral and Brain Sciences 21.4, pp. 499–511. doi: 10.1017/S0140525X98001265.]

If you must keep using `language = {en},` you can try one of the following workarounds.

1. Use a sourcemap to map `en` to `english`.

   ```
   \DeclareSourcemap{
     \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
       \map{
         \step[fieldsource=language,
               match=\regexp{\Aen\Z},
               replace={english}]
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Use `\DeclareRedundantLanguages` to tell `biblatex` that `en` is redundant for English languages.

   ```
   \DeclareRedundantLanguages{en}{english,american,british,
     canadian,australian,newzealand,USenglish,UKenglish}
   ```